# Reference request: Brown Ozawa and strong completely positive approximation property?

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

The notion of a $C^*$-algebra being *nuclear* has many equivalent characterisations.  These are considered in the excellent, modern textbook [$C^*$-Algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/gsm-88) by Brown and Ozawa.  They take as definition that the identity on the $C^*$-algebra $A$ can be point-norm approximated by ccp maps which factor through matrix algebras.

The original definition is that there is only one $C^*$-norm on $A\odot B$, for any $B$.  In the history of the subject, [Kirchberg](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19770760115) and [Choi, Effros](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373876) independently showed that $A$ is nuclear if the identity on $A$ can be point-norm approximated by finite-rank ccp maps from $A$ to itself.  Kirchberg's paper calls this the *strong completely positive approximation property* (SCPAP) but I don't think this is common terminology now.

My questions:

- Is this result in the book by Brown and Ozawa?  (**Edit:** By "this result" I mean precisely: that the SCPAP implies nuclearity.)  I cannot seem to find it, even though it would nicely motivate the CBAP, a weaker approximation property.
- Is there any direct way to get between these two definitions?  Both papers which I cite take quite a long way around, going through work of Lance and tensor products.

My motivation is to try to give a nice, expositionary, motivation of the CBAP from nuclearity; it would be nice to point to a book for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure if it is in Brown and Ozawa, but it is in Pisier's recent book "Tensor Products of C*-algebras and Operator Spaces" as Corollary 10.16. It may also be in his earlier Operator Spaces book, but  my copy isn't with me.

Comment: Great!  That's _exactly_ the sort of clean statement I wanted.  (Sadly I think, on a quick read, that the proof is still involved.  Probably that is unavoidable.)

Comment: @Matthew Daws: There is indeed a bridge connecting two definitions, which is quite robust and works in more general setting. It's the theory of $\delta$-norm. See Section 12 (Theorem 12.7 in particular) in Pisier's Operator Spaces book.